# How can I harden input used with preg_match/replace regex?

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I am working with a PHP script that finds

```
var $_plgCode       = "#{comment(.*?) contentid=(.*?) option=(.*?) contenttitle=(.*?)}#i";
```

and then later uses this in:

```
preg_match_all($this->_plgCode, $_body, $matches);
```

and

```
$_body = preg_replace($this->_plgCode, $output, $_body);
```

The problem is that contenttitle can contain user input and hasn't been hardened at all - so lots of things will break it, like if a user enters }, for example.

What kind of escaping of user input needs to be done on the contenttitle to ensure it doesn't break the REGEX?

Comment: If the `}` character is not in the regex, but in the replacing strings, how could it ever break your regex? It could break resulting HTML, sure, but the regex itself? Nope. Or are you creating _another_ regex with those?

Comment: if a user were to write, for exampe, "This is the } title", then the string becomes:

{comment contentid=100 option=option_name contenttitle=This is the } title}

Comment: You mean the user has entered in the $_body string?

Comment: User has entered part of the $_plgCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: Uhm. No. This question is not about inserting text into a regex.